# Not able to fetch Access token for Azure Devops API

Tags: azure, rest, oauth-2.0, azure-devops

I am not able to fetch the access token for Azure DevOps.

My goal is to work with azure DevOps API without the PAT flow using Powershell.

The steps I followed are as follows:

Registered an app in https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/profile/view  (I am not sure how to test this as locally Since I passed the callback URL as https://localhost:0/)

Used the details to fetch access token in postman

[image]

Getting error as - Could not complete Oauth2.0 login (while using authorization flow)

Getting error as - Error getting access token from client credential flow .could not send request(while using authorization flow)

Comment: According to the FAQs in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#q-i-want-to-debug-my-web-app-locally-can-i-use-localhost-for-the-callback-url-when-i-register-my-app): Azure DevOps Services doesn't allow localhost to be the hostname in your callback URL. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) and [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample).

Comment: Yes updated the /etc/host to have 127.0.0.1 to have a domain name and used that as callback URL as per the documentation

Comment: I followed [this document](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample) and got the access token. Can you try to obtain tokens in this way? In addition, can you share the complete logs in postman console?